# Creating a temporary table with CROSS JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I'm trying to create a temporary table for application data I've got. When I run the sub query it works fine but when I run it within the temporary table parameters it fails with

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'getApplicationsForRespID.app_id' in 'where clause'

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CurrentApplications ENGINE=MEMORY AS 
(
SELECT *, planning_scheme.markus_ra, planning_scheme.metro_or_rural
FROM application
INNER JOIN key_table ON key_table.app_id = application.app_id
INNER JOIN planning_scheme ON planning_scheme.ps_code = application.planning_scheme

CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT key_table.app_id AS app_id2, planning_return.resp_authority AS resp_id
    FROM key_table
    INNER JOIN planning_return ON key_table.return_id = planning_return.return_id

)getApplicationsForRespID

WHERE application.app_id = getApplicationsForRespID.app_id
AND key_table.is_current = 1
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cross join subquery, you have `key_table.app_id AS app_id2`, which means, that no field `getApplicationsForRespID.app_id` exists.

Use `getApplicationsForRespID.app_id2` in the `WHERE` clause instead!